# How can i check TCP connection status when keep alive?

Tags: mule

I am using a client TCP connector with the `keepalive` property set to `true`. It works fine when the connection is established. The problem arises when the server goes down, I do not know the connection status before i send data.

Is there any way I can find the Server/Connection before sending data by raising an exception or an event?

Comment: Why not Ping it, catch the response and then initiate the TCP stream?

Comment: Can i see some example codes ?